# How do i switch to evil-normal-state on save

Tags: spacemacs, evil, osx

I am new to spacemacs and currently save fils by `s-s` (aka: cmd-s). I would like to switch to `evil-normal-state` each time I save. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use `evil`. So I can only report what I found through a short internet search.

Several solutions are suggested there: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4emyt2/how_to_properly_configure_keybindings_for_evil/

I just cite two variants here:

The simplest one is using `:w` instead of `S-s` for saving the buffer.

The next simple thing is adding the following to your init file:

`(add-hook 'after-save-hook #'evil-normal-state)`

Comment: Thank you. That saved my problem. It didn't work when i reloaded my dot file with `spc-f-e-R` but after restarting emacs it worked. It works with `S-s` as well.